# How do I create new tables based on a field value?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

It's been many years since I've used Access, and I'm definitely rusty... I would like to split an existing table into multiple tables based on a single value. For example:
(note the values vary, doesn't matter what they are except for Col C below)

```
Col A |  Col B  | Col C | Col D
--------------------------------
aaa   |  xxx    | app1  | somepath1
bbb   |  yyy    | app1  | somepath2
ccc   |  zzz    | app2  | somepath3
ddd   |  www    | app2  | somepath4
eee   |  vvv    | app3  | somepath5
```

Basically I want to split and create a table called "app1" that has all the rows from app1, a table called "app2" that has all of the rows from app2, etc.

Rather than do this manually with a make table query, copying and pasting each appname into the criteria field, I'd prefer to do this automatically and make it a saved query that can be run on future data.

I tried editing the SQL directly and selecting a distinct appname, then creating a select based off of that, but every thing I've tried gives the error "the field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted". I'm not even sure what that means, because all of my fields are "Long Text", and the data isn't even more than 200 characters in most cases.

Any suggestions how to automate this? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function split()
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set Applist = db.OpenRecordset("select ColC from SourceData group by ColC")
Applist.MoveFirst
Do While Not Applist.EOF
    App = Applist.Fields("ColC").Value
    SQL = "select * into [" & App & "] "
    SQL = SQL & " from [SourceData] where ColC='" & App & "'"
    db.Execute (SQL)
    Applist.MoveNext
    Loop
MsgBox ("Done")
End Function
```

Note - this assumes that the contents of ColC are "nice" - no quotes or brackets, for example.  Spaces should be OK.

Comment: The method of running VBA code has changed a bit over the years apparently. How/where do I actually run this code?

Comment: Create a module and put this in it.  Inside the module, you can click the F5 function key.  Or you can create a macro with a RunCode command in it.

Comment: Thanks -- I did the module route and ran, but had to refresh my table view in order to see the new table names. Thanks, that worked perfectly!